# ShardManagement Binary ShardingKey Max Value

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-elastic-scale

I am currently setting up my `shardmap` manager, shard map ... via the `PowerShell` script provided [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-DB-Elastic-731883db).

While the example uses int as `ShardingKey` type, I have a binary(16) `ShardingKey`, does anyone know how to determine and pass a high key of max binary(16) to `Add-RangeMapping` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Add-RangeMapping` function calls](https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/blob/master/Samples/PowerShell/ShardManagement/ShardManagement.psm1#L313) the [`Range(low, high)` constructor](https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/blob/master/Src/ElasticScale.Client/ShardManagement/Shard/Range.cs#L22). In order to create a range with a max high value, it would need to call the [`Range(low)` constructor](https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/blob/master/Src/ElasticScale.Client/ShardManagement/Shard/Range.cs#L39). So you'll have to edit the `Add-RangeMapping` function appropriately (or just directly call into the library code without using the `Add-RangeMapping` function).

The PowerShell helper scripts don't cover the complete Elastic Database Client Library surface area so you may find a few more gaps.

Comment: Thanks =) you! I was first considering to pass null for high. But then `HighIsMax` is not set.